# Python script to exe on python 3.5

Tags: python, exe

What can I use to go from a python script to an exe on 3.5? Because both py2exe and CxFreeze only support up to 3.4.

Also, would it be possible to create an executable without a bunch of .dll's generated? Because I would like to have just a single .exe to share.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try pyinstaller.
It worked for me fine with python 3.5.

Install `pyinstaller` with the following command

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

and build you exe with `pyinstaller --onefile your_pyfile.py`.
`--onefile` option generates one file of about 6-8 megs max.

Comment: Running fine on py 3.5, thanks. Getting a bootloader error, apparently I have to install one or something

Comment: @FOrp I use win 10 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC. I did not have any errors so far.

Comment: it seems Visual Studio is a requirement for pyinstaller :/

Comment: @FOrp I got just free edition of community, after I have read that for python 3.5 VC 14.0 should be used. So with or without pyinstaller you need VC 14 if you plan using python 3.5 on windows.

Comment: I have been using python 3.5 just fine without it, I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: @FOrp sometimes you will need to install the modules that will be build on your machine, that means then one needs a compiler compatible with python 3.5 on windows. If you plan to use only standard modules you do not need the compiler at all